# TinyMCE 4: How to disable/hide tooltip?

Tags: tinymce

I've just upgraded my TinyMCE to version 4, which seems to have a tooltip by default.

How can I disable/hide the tooltip that appears on mouse-over on any tool-bar item?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've been searching for any possible solution, but so far, I have found nothing in the official documentation.  What I found in the development `tinymce.js` file (uncompressed version) is that tooltip is hardcoded and set to be included every time.

I tried different things to disable the tooltip, by so far, the easiest and safest way I came up with is by using CSS, include this bit of code in the main css file to hide the tooltip forever:

```
.mce-widget.mce-tooltip {
    display: none !important;
}
```

This solution avoids using Javascript/jQuery, and also avoids modifying the source file `tinymce.js`.

Comment: I was looking for a more dynamic solution on tinymce 4.x to be able to enable/disable tooltips. Your solution hides them permanently. It works flawless. So I tried to make a JQuery version of it. Converting your example to JQuery removes all elements while '!important' was not used (probably not JQuery compatible). I look further into it. My solution (on init of tinymce:                 $('.mce-widget[aria-label]').each(function(){  $(this).attr('aria-label', ''); });

Answer (score 0):

I fiddled around and found a dynamic solution using JQuery and tinyMCE 4.x. This solution allows you to enable/disable tooltips inside tinyMCE:

```
tinymce.init({
...
  init_instance_callback : function() {
    $("head").append("<style> .mce-tooltip{ display: none; } </style>"); 
  },
...
```

It does change the class mce-tooltip after tinyMCE is initialised (init_instance_callback). Set 'display: block;' if you want to display the tooltips again. Its not the nicest solution, I know, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the button instance and set its `rendered` state to `false`:

```
var controlIds = editor.theme.panel.rootControl.controlIdLookup;

for (let i in controlIds) {
    if (controlIds[i].tooltip) {
        controlIds[i].tooltip().state.set('rendered', false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS for not showing the pop-over for inserting image and table.

`.tox .tox-pop {display: none !important;}`